# Can't control mouse with Wii remote. CWiiD

Tags: raspberry-pi, mouse

I want to control my mouse on my raspberry pi with a wii remote. I followed [this tutorial here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CWiiD) but I just can't control the mouse (No IR movement and buttons don't do anything).

Connecting works, every button and IR works with `wmgui`, just not with `wminput`.

I don't know where the error is. The issue could be with uinput because just the mouse part isn't working.

Any ideas on what I can try to solve this problem?

---

More infos:

- `uinput` is running within the kernel. Checked with `lsmod | grep "uinput"`
- Tried to run `wminput` with no config, default config, ir_ptr and the config from the tutorial without success.
- I connect via remote desktop to the pi
- There is no hardware mouse connected to the pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you can't see/control your mouse when connected via remote desktop to the pi. When connecting the pi directly to a monitor, you can see that the mouse actually moves when the Wii remote is tilted.

So, it just doesn't work when connected remotely to the pi..